# .js file size became bigger after download

Tags: javascript, file, http, filesystems

I noticed that if i link a js file through the http, like

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

it's size 32.9kb.
However when i download it the size became 110kb... 
[image]

Is there anything to do with this? 
My OS is win 7 64bit.
I believe windows could change file size according to it's file system, but that much?

Comment: The first one is compressed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first one is [gzipped](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gzip) while the second one isn't